# How to control order of equal elements in sort() and sortrows()

Tags: matlab

How do you preserve the order of equal elements in `sort()` and `sortrows()`? (assuming they use the same sorting algorithm)

At first glance, this may seem trivially true because re-ordering equal elements produces an identical array. However, the original ordering can still contain extra info if more columns are involved or if the ordering is applied to a different array.

For example, if we set

```
arr={'a';'b';'c'};
TF=strcmpi(arr,'b')`;

[~,I]=sort(TF,'descend');
```

then `TF=[false;true;false]`. And in `TF`, there are equal elements.

How do I make sure `arr(I)` preserve the relative order of `a` and `c` and output `{'b';'a';'c'}`?

Moreover, when sorting rows using `sortrows()`, or some other native functions, is there a way to apply a secondary ordering on the equal elements based on a different column?

Comment: I think Matlab's `sort` uses quicksort which is stable, i.e. preserves order for equivalent elements.

Comment: ah. I read the linked question and it answered the part about stable sort but I forgot about the secondary ordering... I'll ask the second part in a separate question.

Comment: @M.A: Quicksort is **not** stable.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Thanks for chiming in. Does it mean Matlab `sort` is potentially not stable and there is no way to control it?

Comment: I don’t know how `sort` is implemented. They could have explicitly made it stable. They maybe use something other than Quicksort (though that is the most likely choice). I’m just correcting the statement in the comment above.

Comment: I just added an answer to the linked duplicate showing how you can enforce stability in `sortrows`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: When you say sort `[1:3]` as second value, does it mean `sortrows()` can apply a secondary ordering based on a different vector/column on the equal elements?

Comment: @Argyll: if you set the column to `[1,3]` it sorts first on column 1, and then on column 3. Meaning that equal values in column 1 are sorted according column 3.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Meaning there is no built in ways to do that in `sortrows` right?

Comment: @Argyll: I don’t know if the sorting is stable or not, the docs don’t say. I would implement a non-stable sort, it’s more efficient. `sortrows` by default sorts on all columns, so for numbers and strings equal values are truly equal and stability is not important. I don’t see an option in the docs to control stability. Hence I wrote that answer. But I don’t know if there’s another alternative or not.

Comment: @Argyll: my bad, I just now noticed this statement in the documentation for `sort`: "The order of the elements in B preserves the order of any equal elements in A." I wish they had used the common word "stable", which I searched for... :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I didn't see that either. Good to know. Thanks for pointing it out